# Can I change time zone of ArangoDB's logs?

Tags: time, arangodb

I live in Japan, so wanna change time zone of *ArangoDB's* logs from default to *UTC+9:00*.
Maybe I have to change somewhere of config files but I couldn't make sense.

Comment: @mArm.ch I'm sorry I couldn't vote for your editing because newbie for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time zone is always GMT. You could open a feature request on github https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB/issues maybe a config option can be added. But this needs to be checked.

Comment: I've put a request on the GitHub repository, thanks :)

Comment: Feature added in devel branch: https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB/commit/21c33bdc82d8ce6d6bcd80a9a13b6542bf14c6d7